# Is there a difference in the mechanism of repulsion of 2 north poles vs 2 south poles?

Tags: electromagnetism

Are the strengths of the repulsive forces in these two cases the same? The magnetic field lines in one case "crash" into each other, while in the other case, they try to absorb each other. Physically, is it this crashing of field lines that repel magnets as if the field lines were jets of water? If so, how would you explain repulsion of two south poles? What exactly does a field line consist of?

Comment: I think that you're taking diagrams of field lines associated with magnets a bit too literally.

Comment: "The magnetic field lines in one case 'crash' into each other, while in the other case, they try to absorb each other". Source?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the N and the S pole of the magnet. The designation is just a convention. The direction of the B field from N to S is also just a convention.